# Laravel route allow any parameter not working

Tags: php, laravel

Any help why this is not working,I am using Laravel 5.4 version ,this is are my routes

app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes();
    $this->mapExampleRoutes();
}
protected function mapExampleRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('example')
         ->middleware('example')
         ->namespace($this->namespace.'\\Examle')
         ->group(base_path('routes/example.php'));
}
```

routes\example.php

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('example.app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

$ php artisan route:list

```
+--------+-----------+-----------------+------+----------+-------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI             | Name | Action   | Middleware  |
+--------+-----------+-----------------+------+----------+-------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /               |      | Closure  | web         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | example/{any}   |      | Closure  | example     |
+--------+-----------+-----------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

The problem is when I try to access /example  it returns not found (NotFoundHttpException) ,
other routes are working , for example, /example/login .
any idea why this one is not working ?

Comment: how your routes.php look like ? are you sure that example.php is included ?

Comment: thanks for add comment . look at [RouteServiceProvider.php].
 include [routes/example.php] by this file.
 ~Laravel 5.3 version upgrade, add app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php and include routing files (routes/web.php and routes/api.php)

Comment: I am sorry if my writing isnot to answer your questions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('{any?}', function () {
    return view('example.app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

I removed the leading slash (/) and added a question mark (?) to indicate the slug is optional.

Comment: Then please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark. Other people will know this was the right answer and I also get some score on this site as a reward :)

Comment: I tried to ask question for the first time... Many thanks for the thought. :)